# RegionPlot3D Error

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I have the following command:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  Log[p1/(1 + p2)] > 0, {p1, 0, 0.5}, {p2, 0.5, 1}, {C, 0, 1}]
```

and my *Mathematica* 9 gave me the following error message:

> RegionPlot3D::boolf: "Log[p1/(1+p2)]>0 must be a Boolean function."

I have no idea why `Log[p1/(1+p2)]>0` is not a Boolean function. It just looks like an innocent inequality that should work in `RegionPlot3D`.

Note: I have simplified the inequality so it does not involve `C`, but in the original version it does contain `C`.

Comment: I think that's because your `p1` begin with `0`, where the `Log[p1/(1 + p2)]` is undefined. Try `TrueQ[Log[p1/(1 + p2)] > -2]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that's because your `p1` begin with `0`, where the `Log[p1/(1 + p2)]` is undefined. You could set the start point a little greater than `0`, or you could try `TrueQ[Log[p1/(1 + p2)] > -2]`, which will give `False` for any case that it's argument is not explicit `True`.

btw. You should not use `C`, which is [a system reserved function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/C.html), as your variable name.

Comment: Similarly, avoid `K` which does not have its own doc page, but shows up via `?K`.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks! Didn't know that! I generally avoid any symbol names begin with upper-case.

Comment: It's good advice. I tend to ignore it, especially for my own packages. To me a packaged function needs to be capitalized.